# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: How does the difference between the two terms change?

Tags: matrices, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in matrix form is given by

$||\mathbf{x}^HAA^H\mathbf{y}||^2 \le (\mathbf{x}^HAA^H\mathbf{x})(\mathbf{y}^HAA^H\mathbf{y})$

where $[\cdot]^H$ denotes conjugate transpose.

The above equality holds when $A^H\mathbf{x}=\lambda A^H\mathbf{y}$, where $\lambda$ is a complex constant.

My question is: how does the difference $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},A)$ between the two terms of the inequality vary as $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},A$ changes?

My first guess:

the difference

$f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},A)=(\mathbf{x}^HAA^H\mathbf{x})(\mathbf{y}^HAA^H\mathbf{y})-||\mathbf{x}^HAA^H\mathbf{y}||^2$

increases as the distance between the two vectors

$d=||A^H\mathbf{x}-A^H\mathbf{y}||$

increases. But I don't know how to prove or disprove it.

Hope you can help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: First, the difference is proportional to the scale of $x$, $y$ and $A$, if we fixed the scale of those variables, then intuitively the difference should be determined by the "angle" between $A^H x$ and $A^H y$

Comment: @VezenBU Can you be more specific?